# Instance vs. Member Variables python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, instance

What is the difference between instance and member variables in python 3 and how would you create them?
We are just learning how to create classes in python 3 and I do not understand these variable types.

Can I set them before the "__ init __ " method?

I am writing a code where ID needs to be an instance variable and balance and annualInterestRate need to be member variables. This is what I have for that:

```
    def __init__(self, ID=0, initialbalance=100.0, annualInterestRate=0.0):
        self.__ID = int(ID)
        self.__balance = float(initialbalance)
        self.__annualInterestRate = float(annualInterestRate)
```

To make Id a class variable, should I set it to the amount before "__ init __"? I do need to be able to change the value later in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Class attributes are attributes which are owned by the class itself. They will be shared by all the instances of the class. Therefore they have the same value for every instance. Member variables are specific only to the member of a class, and can have different values for each instance of the class.

This shows a class attribute. Notice that the `a` is the same across all instances.

```
>>> class A:
...     a = "I am a class attribute!"
... 
>>> x = A()
>>> y = A()
>>> x.a
'I am a class attribute!'
>>> y.a
'I am a class attribute!'
>>> A.a
'I am a class attribute!'
```

Now if we try to change it in one, it will change in all.

```
>>> A.a = "I am changed now"
>>> A.a
'I am changed now'
>>> x.a
'I am changed now'
>>> y.a
'I am changed now'
```

This shows member variables and how they are specific to each instance. Notice that `a` is defined within the `__init__` function this time, making it a member variable, not a class variable.

```
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 10
>>> x = B()
>>> y = B()
>>> x.a
10
>>> y.a
10
>>> y.a = 12
>>> x.a
10
>>> y.a
12
```

In this class, `self.a` is given a default value of 10. In the `y` instance of the class, it is changed to 12 (`y.a = 12`). The `x` instance of the class remains the default value of 10.

The beginning part of this answer was taken from the [Class and Instance Attributes](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php) page on Python Course